# Sudoku Solver in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

We made a matrix library for scheme in class (documentation here: 
http://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-pub/c211/wombat/docs/c211-matrix.htm

So as a little project I decided to do with matrices is a Sudoku solver. (This is not for credit, this was given as sort of a practice with matrices before a test).

I've gotten mostly through the program so far I'm just stuck on a couple final functions.

I want to write a function called check-block that will take a north-west-corner row a north-west-corner column and a value and check and see if that value can go in that block. So basically the top left of one of the Sudoku 3X3 boxes and itll need to check if the number has all ready occurred or not. I have a check-row and check-col function below that checks each specific row and column to see if a number can go there, but it starts at the very first column or square each time, not sure how to go about making it start from a given northwest corner.

It'd start of something like:

```
(define (check-block nwr nwc val))
```

I'm assuming I'll have to use some sort of loop to check each part of the block.

After this I want to write something called valid? which takes a row index r, a column index c, and a value val and checks that it is possible to put the value in the given position.

Those two I really am stuck on, then to end it I know how to think of it as an algorithm stand point. Which is I need four more functions solve, try-row, try-cell, and try-value.

The idea is that solve simply calls try-row 0 which starts filling the puzzle from row 0. The procedure try-row assumes that all the previous rows are properly filled and, if the puzzle is not finished, attempts to make progress by calling (try-cell r 0). The procedure try-cell assumes all the previous rows and the columns to the left are properly filled. If the current row is filled, it proceeds to the next row. If the current cell is not blank, it skips it. Otherwise, if the current cell is blank, it calls (try-value r c 1) which attempts to fill the current cell with 1. The procedure try-value takes the coordinates of a cell and a value v to be placed in the given position. If the value exceeds 9 then the procedure, having failed, returns. If it is possible to put the given value, the procedure tries the next value. If it is possible to put the given value, the board is modified, and the computation proceeds by trying to fill the next cell. If the attempt to fill the next fails, the added value is removed, and the next value is tried.

So here is the code I have so far:

```
;This function defines an empty cell as _
(define empty #\_)

;This makes it so there are 9 rows in the matrix
(define rows 9)

;This makes it so there are 9 columns in the matrix
(define cols 9)

;This makes it soa block size is considered 3X3
(define block-size 3)

;This makes board be the matri
(define board (make-matrix rows cols empty))

;This function physically builds the matrix
(define read-puzzle
   (lambda (fname)
     (with-input-from-file
       fname
       (lambda ()
         (let row-loop ([r 0])
           (unless (= r rows)
             (let col-loop ([c 0])
               (if (= c cols)
                   (row-loop (add1 r))
                   (begin
                     (matrix-set! board r c (read-cell))
                     (col-loop (add1 c)))))))))))

;This reads what cell has what value
(define read-cell
   (lambda () (let ([c (read)]) (if (eq? c '-) empty c))))

;This function checks a specific cell to see if it is blank or has a value
(define (blank? r c)
  (equal? empty (matrix-ref board r c)))

;This clears the board to an empty 9x9 matrix
(define (clear-board)
  (set! board (make-matrix rows cols empty)))

;This function checks if the value given can be put in that row by checking
;if that value all ready occurs in that row giving #t if it doesnt occur and
;#f if it does occur
(define (check-row r val)
  (define (cr-helper r c val)
    (cond
      [(>= c cols) #t]
      [(equal? val (matrix-ref board r c)) #f]
      [else (cr-helper r (add1 c) val)]))
   (cr-helper r 0 val))

;This function checks if the value given can be put in that column by checking
;if that value all ready occurs in that column giving #t if it doesnt occur and
;#f if it does occur
(define (check-col c val)
 (define (cc-helper r c val)
   (cond
     [(>= r rows) #t]
     [(equal? val (matrix-ref board r c)) #f]
     [else (cc-helper (add1 r) c val)]))
  (cc-helper 0 c val))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your check-block function will need two nested loops, one loop that advances by rows and one loop that advances by columns, starting from the northwest corner. Each of the two loops checks the cell at an offset of 0, 1 or 2 from the northwest corner, and returns #f if it is the same as the target number.

I wrote a somewhat different Sudoku solver based on lists rather than matrices. I'll repeat the code below; you can see the explanation at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2009/02/19/sudoku/).

```
(define (sudoku puzzle)
  (define (safe? filled digit cell)
    (cond ((null? filled) #t)
          ((and (= (vector-ref (car filled) 0) (vector-ref cell 0))
                (char=? (vector-ref (car filled) 3) digit)) #f)
          ((and (= (vector-ref (car filled) 1) (vector-ref cell 1))
                (char=? (vector-ref (car filled) 3) digit)) #f)
          ((and (= (vector-ref (car filled) 2) (vector-ref cell 2))
                (char=? (vector-ref (car filled) 3) digit)) #f)
          (else (safe? (cdr filled) digit cell))))
  (define (next digit) (integer->char (+ (char->integer digit) 1)))
  (define (new old digit) (vector (vector-ref old 0) (vector-ref old 1) (vector-ref old 2) digit))
  (let scan ((s 0) (empty '()) (filled '()))
    (if (< s 81)
        (let* ((row (quotient s 9))
               (col (modulo s 9))
               (box (+ (* (quotient row 3) 3) (quotient col 3)))
               (digit (string-ref puzzle s))
               (cell (vector row col box digit)))
          (if (char=? digit #\0)
              (scan (+ s 1) (cons cell empty) filled)
              (scan (+ s 1) empty (cons cell filled))))
        (let solve ((empty empty) (filled filled))
          (if (pair? empty)
              (let try ((cell (car empty)) (digit (next (vector-ref (car empty) 3))))
                (cond ((char<? #\9 digit) ; backtrack
                        (solve (cons (car filled) (cons (new cell #\0) (cdr empty))) (cdr filled)))
                      ((safe? filled digit cell) ; advance
                        (solve (cdr empty) (cons (new cell digit) filled)))
                      (else (try cell (next digit))))) ; try next digit
              (let ((str (make-string 81 #\0)))
                (do ((filled filled (cdr filled))) ((null? filled) str)
                  (let* ((cell (car filled)) (s (+ (* (vector-ref cell 0) 9) (vector-ref cell 1))))
                    (string-set! str s (vector-ref cell 3))))))))))
```

A Sudoku puzzle is represented as an 81-character string, in row-major order, with empty cells represented as zero. Here is a sample solution:

```
> (sudoku "700100000020000015000006390200018000040090070000750003078500000560000040000001002")
"789135624623947815451286397237418569845693271916752483178524936562379148394861752"
```

You can run the program at http://programmingpraxis.codepad.org/PB1czuyF. 
You might also enjoy the [matrix library](http://programmingpraxis.com/contents/standard-prelude/#matrices) in my [Standard Prelude](http://programmingpraxis.com/contents/standard-prelude).